# What is the size of Procrustes matrix?

Tags: optimization, procrustes-analysis

Is there a contradiction in the presentations of orthogonal Procrustes rotation problem?

In Matrix Computations by Golub&Van Loan (1) the orthogonal Procrustes problem is posed as an optimal rotation of data matrix $B$ into $A$, that is to minimize the Frobenius norm of the matrix $A-BQ$. $A$ and $B$ are data matrices that have $m$ rows and $p$ columns. The matrix $Q$ has $p$ rows and $p$ columns. It is not explained what $m$ and $p$ mean: they can correspond either to dimensionality of vectors or to the number of experiments. But the attached Scipy code (2) suggests that $p$ corresponds to the dimensionality of vectors. So according to the code, the data matrices $A$ and $B$ contain observations as rows. But if we have rows as observations and want to apply a transformation of each observations using a matrix, then the attached discussion (3) explains that the transformation should be rather B.dot(Q.T).

My question: should the transformation formula be B.dot(Q.T) rather than B.dot(Q)?

Links:

1. Matric computations https://github.com/CompPhysics/ComputationalPhysicsMSU/blob/master/doc/Lectures/Golub%2C%20Van%20Loan%20-%20Matrix%20Computations.pdf)
2. Scipy code https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.orthogonal_procrustes.html
3. How to transform vectors in a data matrix?
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512833/how-can-i-apply-a-matrix-transform-to-each-row-of-a-numpy-array-efficiently